# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I've created an interface called "IPerson" in new TypeScript file (.ts):

```
export interface IPerson {
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    age:number;
    sayHi:()=> string;
}
```

when I try to import and create a new object in "test.ts" based on that interface:

```
import {IPerson} from './interfaces/person.interface';
let p1:IPerson = {
    firstName:"Ali",
    lastName:"Helmi",
    age:35,
    sayHi:()=>`Hi Ali`
}
```

After running this command in the terminal:

> node test.js

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in typescript

Could you pleas help me find the error and fix it?

Thank you!